# Data structure for storing variables in an interpreted language

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, global-variables, language-design, compiler-construction

I am designing my own experimental scripting language for the purpose of embedding it in my bigger application.

Almost everything I wanted to do was programmed smoothly, but the "simple" act of storing variables in memory appeared to be the hardest part here. I don't know how to store them to allow all type checking, global variables and special flags on them. First look at a sample code:

```
a = 1
b = 2

someFunction()
  print(a)   --> This should read the global variable and print `1`
  a = 3      --> Now `a` should become a local variable of this function
                 and the global `a` remain unchanged
  x = 4      --> `x` should always be local of this function
end
```

I call the "locality" of variables their `level`s so variables in nested blocks have a higher level. In the above code, `a` and `b` are level 1 variables. Local variables of someFunction will have level 2. The first line of the function should read the global variable `a` (level 1) but the second line should create a variable again called `a` but with level 2 that shadows the global `a` from that point onwards. The third line should create the variable `x` with level 2. How to store and keep track of all these in memory?

**What I tried so far:**

Method 1: Storing maps of `variable=>value` in array of levels:

```
variables
{
    level=1 //global variables
    {
        a => 1,
        b => 2
    },
    level=2 //function variables
    {
        a => 3,
        x => 4
    }
}
```

But that will make variable look-up really slow since one has to search all the levels for a given variable.

Method 2: Storing the (variable, level) pairs as keys of a map:

```
variables
{
    (a, 1) => 1, //global
    (b, 1) => 2, //global
    (a, 2) => 3, //function
    (x, 2) => 3  //function
}
```

This has the same problem as before since we have to try the pair (variable, level) with all possible levels for a given variable.

What method should I use for optimal memory usage and fastest access time?

**Additional notes:**

I know about how variables are managed on stack and heap on other "real" languages, but I find it tricky to do this on an interpreted language. "This mustn't be how Lua and Python do that," I always think. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm trying to store the variable in maps and internal C++ structures.

And finally, this is how I represent a variable. Do you think it's big and there can be more memory-efficient representations? (I've also tried to put the "Level" as a member here but it had the same problem as the other too.)

```
struct Member
{
    uchar type;  //0=num, 1=str, 2=function, 3=array, etc
    uchar flags; //0x80 = read-only, 0x40 = write-only, etc
    union {
        long double value_num;
        char* value_str;
        int value_func;
        //etc
    };
};
```

Comment: I would use a map that maps each variable name to a stack of variable instances. When you create a new variable on a level you push this variable on the stack and the top most element on the stack holds the currently visible variable instance with this name. You also have to maintain a list of allocated variables for each level to pop the variables off the stack when leaving the level. Hope that makes sense, I never designed a language myself.

Comment: You can simply use a stack of arrays and some form of the de Bruijn indexes. Perform a primitive "compilation" step before interpreting, by resolving all the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy thing to do, similar to your array, is to maintain a stack of maps. Each map contains the bindings for that scope. To bind a variable, add it to the top map; to look up a variable, start at the top of the stack and stop when you reach a map that contains a binding for that variable. Search takes a little bit, but starting from the top/end you only have to search until you find it — in most cases, this search will not be very long.

You can also make the stack implicit by encapsulating this logic in an `Environment` class that has local bindings and an inherited environment used for resolving unknown variables. Need to go into a new scope? Create a new environment with the current environment as its base, use it, then discard it when the scope is finished. The root/global environment can just have a null inherited environment. This is what I would probably do.

Comment: It looks like this is how Python does things: [see Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine)

Answer (score 2):

Its worth noting that if, inside a function, you don't have access to any variables from the caller function, it lowers the number of levels you need to look at. For example:

```
variable a;

function one() {
    variable b;
    // in this function, we can see the global a, local b
    two();
}

function two() {
    // in this function, we can see the global a, local c
    // we cannot see the local b of our caller
    variable c;
    while (true) {
        variable d;
        // here we can see local d, local c, global a
    }
}
```

The idea being that function boundaries limit the visibility of variables, with the global scope being "special".

That being said, you can consider removing the specialness of global variables, but allowing the code to specify that they want access to non-local variables

```
variable a;

function one() {
    global a; // or upvar #0 a;
    variable b;
    // in this function, we can see the global a, local b
    two();
}

function two() {
    // in this function, we can see the local c
    // and the local b of our caller
    // (since we specifically say we want access to "b" one level up)
    upvar 1 b;
    variable c;
}
```

It looks complicated at first, but it's really easy to understand once you get used to it (upvar is a construct from the Tcl programming language). What it allows you is access to variables in your caller's scope, but it avoids some of the costly lookup involved by requiring that you specify exactly where that variable comes from (with 1 being one level up the call stack, 2 being two levels up, and #0 being "special" in saying "the uppermost call stack, the global)